# Configuring view with multi-select filter for exclusive subject matching

Tags: views, 10

How can I configure a Drupal 10 View with a multi-select exposed filter to display teachers who exclusively teach selected subjects?

Currently, the filter shows teachers who teach any of the selected subjects (math, computer science),
but I want it to only display teachers who teach all of the selected subjects simultaneously, such as both math and computer science.

I tried change it in `hook_views_query_alter()`, but it fails.

In `hook_views_query_alter()` comes an array of subjects.

```php
$selected_subjects = 
$view->exposed_data['field_teacher_technology_target_id'];
```

`$selected_subjects` contains `[26:'26', 65:'65']`; 26 and 65 are the subject IDs.

How can I change the code to get only the accounts who who have both the values?

In view:

```sql
WHERE ("node_field_data"."type" IN ('teacher')) AND 
(("paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_0"."field_teacher_technology_target_id" = '26') AND 
("paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_1"."field_teacher_technology_target_id" = '65'))
```

I also tried change '#conjunction' from 'OR' to 'AND', but it  doen't helped.

Please help.

In Default view query I have:
SELECT "node_field_data"."title" AS "node_field_data_title", "node__field_teacher_profile_picture"."field_teacher_profile_picture_target_id" AS "node__field_teacher_profile_picture_field_teacher_profile_pict", "node__field_teacher_surname"."field_teacher_surname_value" AS "node__field_teacher_surname_field_teacher_surname_value", "node__field_teacher_phone"."field_teacher_phone_value" AS "node__field_teacher_phone_field_teacher_phone_value", "node__field_teacher_english_level"."field_teacher_english_level_value" AS "node__field_teacher_english_level_field_teacher_english_level_", "node_field_data"."status" AS "node_field_data_status", "node__field_teacher_type_activity"."field_teacher_type_activity_target_id" AS "node__field_teacher_type_activity_field_teacher_type_activity_", "node__field_teacher_status"."field_teacher_status_value" AS "node__field_teacher_status_field_teacher_status_value", "node__field_teacher_agreement"."field_teacher_agreement_value" AS "node__field_teacher_agreement_field_teacher_agreement_value", "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_currency"."field_currency_target_id" AS "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph", "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_fee_price"."field_fee_price_value" AS "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph_1", "node__field_teacher_working_days_hours"."field_teacher_working_days_hours_value" AS "node__field_teacher_working_days_hours_field_teacher_working_d", "node__field_teacher_hours_per_week"."field_teacher_hours_per_week_value" AS "node__field_teacher_hours_per_week_field_teacher_hours_per_wee", "node__field_teacher_timezone"."field_teacher_timezone_value" AS "node__field_teacher_timezone_field_teacher_timezone_value", "node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric"."field_teacher_timezone_numeric_value" AS "node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric_field_teacher_timezone_nu", MAX(paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_level.field_teacher_level_value) AS "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__", STDDEV_POP(paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_proven.field_teacher_proven_value) AS "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies___1", MIN(node_field_data.nid) AS "nid_1", MIN(paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies.id) AS "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies_i", MIN(paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee.id) AS "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee_id"
FROM
{node_field_data} "node_field_data"
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_technologies} "node__field_teacher_technologies" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_technologies.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_technologies.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {paragraphs_item_field_data} "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies" ON node__field_teacher_technologies.field_teacher_technologies_target_revision_id = paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies.revision_id
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_fee} "node__field_teacher_fee" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_fee.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_fee.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {paragraphs_item_field_data} "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee" ON node__field_teacher_fee.field_teacher_fee_target_revision_id = paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee.revision_id
LEFT JOIN {paragraph__field_teacher_technology} "paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_0" ON paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies.id = paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_0.entity_id AND paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_0.field_teacher_technology_target_id = '26'
LEFT JOIN {paragraph__field_teacher_technology} "paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_1" ON paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies.id = paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_1.entity_id AND paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_1.field_teacher_technology_target_id = '65'
LEFT JOIN {paragraph__field_fee_price} "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_fee_price" ON paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee.id = paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_fee_price.entity_id AND paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_fee_price.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric} "node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_profile_picture} "node__field_teacher_profile_picture" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_profile_picture.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_profile_picture.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_surname} "node__field_teacher_surname" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_surname.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_surname.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_phone} "node__field_teacher_phone" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_phone.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_phone.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_email} "node__field_teacher_email" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_email.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_email.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_payment_method} "node__field_teacher_payment_method" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_payment_method.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_payment_method.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_english_level} "node__field_teacher_english_level" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_english_level.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_english_level.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_type_activity} "node__field_teacher_type_activity" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_type_activity.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_type_activity.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_status} "node__field_teacher_status" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_status.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_status.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_agreement} "node__field_teacher_agreement" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_agreement.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_agreement.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {paragraph__field_currency} "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_currency" ON paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee.id = paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_currency.entity_id AND paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_currency.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_working_days_hours} "node__field_teacher_working_days_hours" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_working_days_hours.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_working_days_hours.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_hours_per_week} "node__field_teacher_hours_per_week" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_hours_per_week.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_hours_per_week.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_working_days} "node__field_teacher_working_days" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_working_days.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_working_days.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_teacher_timezone} "node__field_teacher_timezone" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_teacher_timezone.entity_id AND node__field_teacher_timezone.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {paragraph__field_teacher_level} "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_level" ON paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies.id = paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_level.entity_id AND paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_level.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {paragraph__field_teacher_proven} "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_proven" ON paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies.id = paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_proven.entity_id AND paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__paragraph__field_teacher_proven.deleted = '0'
WHERE ("node_field_data"."type" IN ('teacher')) AND (("paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_0"."field_teacher_technology_target_id" = '26') OR ("paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_1"."field_teacher_technology_target_id" = '65')) AND ("paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph__field_fee_price"."field_fee_price_value" BETWEEN '0' AND '1000') AND ("node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric"."field_teacher_timezone_numeric_value" BETWEEN '-12' AND '12')
GROUP BY "node_field_data"."nid", "node_field_data_title", "node__field_teacher_profile_picture_field_teacher_profile_pict", "node__field_teacher_surname_field_teacher_surname_value", "node__field_teacher_phone_field_teacher_phone_value", "node__field_teacher_english_level_field_teacher_english_level_", "node_field_data_status", "node__field_teacher_type_activity_field_teacher_type_activity_", "node__field_teacher_status_field_teacher_status_value", "node__field_teacher_agreement_field_teacher_agreement_value", "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph", "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph_1", "node__field_teacher_working_days_hours_field_teacher_working_d", "node__field_teacher_hours_per_week_field_teacher_hours_per_wee", "node__field_teacher_timezone_field_teacher_timezone_value", "node__field_teacher_timezone_numeric_field_teacher_timezone_nu"
ORDER BY "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies__" DESC, "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_technologies___1" DESC, "paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_teacher_fee__paragraph_1" ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
It shows all teachers who have technologies 26 or 65.
2 teachers have 26 (one of them have also 65 technology),
1 teacher only have 65.

I changed 'WHERE' condition to
(("paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_0"."field_teacher_technology_target_id" = '26')
AND ("paragraph__field_teacher_technology_value_1"."field_teacher_technology_target_id" = '65'))

But now I don't see any teacher. Why?
I want see as rezult only teachers who have just 26 AND 65
What I do wrong?

Comment: Posting your code will help to fix your code.

Comment: Please review. @Hudri